# How to change the font of URL in the bibliography

Tags: fonts, biblatex, formatting, natbib, urls

When using the `natbib` package the URLs are printed and formatted in the bibliography in a different font from the rest of the document which looks nasty i.e. monospace Typewriter.

I am having difficulty making it the same font as the rest of the bibliography.

Comment: @Audrey The reason for the similar question is that I was looking for an answer to this problem for a very long time and my searches found nothing for ages. The reason being that the previous questions asked arn't very clear and dont use the right key words for someone whos not sure what to search for the solve the problem. I posted this question to aid someone who needs a quick answer in the future.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `url` package and place in the latex preamble:

```
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
```

If you are using any bibliography style package like apacite of IEEEtrans put the

```
\urlstyle{same} % or \urlstyle{rm}
```

after the style line like the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\urlstyle{rm}
```